# Django auto increasing PositiveIntegerField per ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the below django model is it possible to make the `position` field auto increment per ForeignKey to the `ChatGroup` model

```py
class Channel(Model):
    chat_group = models.ForeignKey(ChatGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=("chat_group", "position")
            )
        ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoField. But the recommended way is save the actual ForeignKey Value.